# Fit a json string to a DataFrame using a schema

Tags: json, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have a schema that looks like this:

```
StructType(StructField(keys,org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7,true))
```

I have a json string(that matches this schema) that I need to convert to fit the above schema.

```
"{"keys" : [2.0, 1.0]}"
```

How I proceed to get a dataframe out of this string to get a DataFrame that matches my schema?
Following are the steps I have tried in a scala notebook:

```
val rddData2 = sc.parallelize("""{"keys" : [1.0 , 2.0] }""" :: Nil)
val in = session.read.schema(schema).json(rddData2)
in.show
```

This is the output being shown:

```
+-----------+
|keys       |        
+-----------+
|null       |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a *json string* as

```
val jsonString = """{"keys" : [2.0, 1.0]}"""
```

then you can create a `dataframe` without `schema` as

```
val jsonRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(jsonString))
val df = sqlContext.read.json(jsonRdd)
```

which should give you

```
+----------+
|keys      |
+----------+
|[2.0, 1.0]|
+----------+
```

with `schema`

```
root
 |-- keys: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

Now if you want to convert the *array column* created by default to *Vector*, then you would need a `udf` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def vectorUdf = udf((array: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Double]) => org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors.dense(Array(array: _*)))
```

and call the `udf` function using `.withColumn` as

```
df.withColumn("keys", vectorUdf(col("keys")))
```

You should be getting *dataframe* with `schema` as

```
root
 |-- keys: vector (nullable = true)
```